# "compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'" Error when trying to output application in AAB format in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dependencies, android-app-bundle

I coded an application with Flutter, I want to get an output of the application in appbundle (aab) format. The 2 libraries I use cause the same error.

> Execution failed for task ':agora_uikit:compileReleaseKotlin'.

> Execution failed for task ':emoji_picker_flutter:compileReleaseKotlin'.

Both have the same description of the error message:

> 'compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileReleaseKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.'

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URBxd.png)

I checked my build.gradle file at project level and application level many times. I tried to solve the problem with ChatGPT for hours. The only suggestion he gave me was to change this part

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
```

I tried many different variations like following:

```
JavaVersion.VERSION_17
jvmTarget = '17'
```

```
JavaVersion.VERSION_11
jvmTarget = '11'
```

```
JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
jvmTarget = '1.8'
```

Btw, my kotlin version: 1.9.0

**I am grateful in advance for any help.**

Comment: i think you need to change jdk  version , In my case i add jdk 11 from oracle and add node 16

Comment: Can you describe exactly how to do it? I've never done it before.

Comment: open android Studio click on IDE and project Setting -> SDK Manager -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Click on Gradle JDK -> Download JDK -> select 11 -> Download. 

for NODE :- you need to add nvm to manage node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem is caused by a bug. I found a workaround.

Add the following command to your gradle.porperties file.

> kotlin.jvm.target.validation.mode = IGNORE

[SolutionScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdvuA.png)